# How to set the color of ticks in Dial Chart of AChartEngine

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

Now i can create the `DialChart` of `AChartEngine` like this

[image: image one]
<sub>(source: [ppt.cc](http://ppt.cc/bKiM@.jpg))</sub>

but i don't know how to set the background color of the ticks,like this one

[image: image two]
<sub>(source: [ppt.cc](http://ppt.cc/NuNv@.jpg))</sub>

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can your ticks color by using this method
       renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.parseColor("hexa decimal color code"));
It will works finely.

Comment: finally i make a background graph and put achartengine in relativelayout with the background.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly, renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.parseColor("hexa decimal color code")) is not the real solution to display the dial chart like the picture shows. The mentioned renderer method sets only the the single ticks' color but it does not set such a coloured scale. Is there another hint how to layout the dial chart.

Regards
anko